# XY prob: How do I issue a bunch of msgs simultaneously?

Tags: elm

Almost definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but I can't think of a concise way to phrase what I'm trying to do.

I have a textarea. Inside this text area, the user enters a comma-separated list of ID numbers. When they click "Fetch", I split their input on commas, to get multiple string values, and each of those string values gets passed to a function that makes a HTTP request to my API getting info on the item.

That's where I stumble. Right now I have these parts:

- `getInfo : String -> Cmd Msg`, takes an ID string and ultimately fires `Http.send`
- `type Msg = Fetch String`, where `Fetch idStr -> (model, getInfo idStr)`

I sort of want to take my textarea's input and say `String.split "," |> List.map (\id -> getInfo id)`. Except I don't know what to do with the `List Msg` that would give me, I want to fire each of those msgs off, but Elm doesn't work that way?

While reading I found `Cmd.batch`, but there's not really any info on it in the docs so I'm not sure if that's what I want or how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Cmd.batch` can batch multiple cmds into one cmd.

For example (via new message: `FetchAll`):

```
FetchAll idsStr ->
  let
    cmds = String.split "," idsStr |> List.map (\id -> getInfo id)
  in (model, Cmd.batch cmds)
```

also, `(model, Cmd.batch cmds)` can be written as `model ! cmds`